# What does the clang -cc1 option do?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I'm a newbie in `clang`. I have read a paper about source to source transformation from `cuda` to `opencl` using `clang` compiler front end.

Can anyone tell me why the option `-cc1` is sometimes used?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The Clang compiler front-end has several additional Clang specific features which are not exposed through the GCC compatibility driver interface. The `-cc1` argument indicates that the compiler front-end is to be used, and not the driver. The clang `-cc1` functionality implements the core compiler functionality.

So, simply speaking. If you do not give `-cc1` then you can expect the "look&feel" of standard GCC. That is the vast majority of compiler flags work just like you would expect them to work with GCC. If you pass the option "-cc1" then you get the Clang compiler flag set. Thus, there might be differences to GCC.

Hope that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Why does `clang -cc1` not return immediately? I was hoping to set an alias for a `clang -cc1` command with many arguments. When running it with no arguments I'd like it to return something like `clang-7: error: no input files`.

Comment: You can test if stdin (0) is open in a terminal with `[ -t 0 ]`, as in `alias cc1='if [ -t 0 ]; then clang -cc1; else echo No; fi'`. You could also look at your own arguments from a wrapper function, like `alias cc1='(){ [ $# > 0 ] &&... }'`; Try this, it aborts the clang call if it can't read any of the args and stdin is on the terminal. `alias cc1='(){ go=false; for a do { [ -r "$a" ] || continue; go=true }; done; if ! $go && [ -t 0 ]; then echo "Sorry" 1>&2; else clang -cc1 $@; fi }'`. I don't think `[ -r "$a" ]` is bulletproof, but it's better than just `$#` and that's better than nothing.

Comment: If I wasn't clear, that's what I think happened - without arguments, clang falls back on reading from stdin, then "hangs" indefinitely waiting for the end-of-file. (You can send it one with ctrl+d, but you may as well ctrl+c.) The developers should already be aware of things like the TTY flag, so I have to assume they chose to leave it. This is the front end we're talking about, maybe it's designed for interaction, like Cling, their "C++ interpreter".

Answer (score 17):

The usual compiler consists of so-called compiler driver, which knows how to execute compiler itself, assembler, linker, etc. and compiler itself which just takes the source code (sometimes already preprocessed) and emit assembler/object code.

Clang implements all these components in the single binary, the difference is just the cmdline. Here `clang -cc1` invokes the compiler itself with its internal/undocumented set of options, etc.